# FCKeditor Upload feature not working, no error

Tags: php, apache, upload, file-upload, fckeditor

Using FCKeditor (2.6.5) When I use the upload feature it acts as if it has worked (no errors) but does not upload a file. I can view other files in the upload folder with the file manager that I ftp in and can also create folders with fck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the FCKeditor configuration file for the correct values, and have you set permissions in the upload folder to be writable for whatever process is running the upload script?

Answer (score 2):

I can solve the problem editing the config.php located in

```
  \fckeditor\editor\filemanager\connectors\php\config.php
```

Putting the absolute path correctly:

```
// Path to user files relative to the document root.
$Config['UserFilesPath'] = '/userfiles/' ;

// Fill the following value it you prefer to specify the absolute path for the
// user files directory. Useful if you are using a virtual directory, symbolic
// link or alias. Examples: 'C:\\MySite\\userfiles\\' or '/root/mysite/userfiles/'.
// Attention: The above 'UserFilesPath' must point to the same directory.
$Config['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] =
```

Comment: thank you. my problem was putting the absolute path incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Just been through this myself. Key was to to place an error handler around the PHP FckEditor FileUpload function where the famous "move_uploaded_file" function call is located. For me it was a permissions issue such that the process under which php runs did not have write permission into my web server owned destination file directory. So as I dont have admin to the server I had two options, give enough permissions such that php could write to it (start with full and prove it works) then wynd it back OR secondly use PHP ftp functions to copy the file from its temp location to the wed server owned directory. They key is to use the same ftp user you use to upload your web content.